# Is this proof by contradiction for the Archimedean Property correct?

Tags: proof-verification

I'm just starting to learn how to use proofs by contradiction, and I am just wondering if this works.

Theorem (Archimedean Property):
If $a$ and $b$ are any positive integers, then there exists a positive integer $n$ such that $na \geq b$.

Proof:

Suppose not. Suppose that there exists a positive integer $a$ and $b$ such that for all positive integer $n$, we have $na<b$. Let $n=b$, so $ab<b\Rightarrow \frac{ab}{b}<\frac{b}{b}\Rightarrow a<1.$ Thus, $a$ is a positive integer and $a$ is less than $1$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: In your solution, I would suggest writing out the reasoning behind the implications, but, other than that, it looks good to me (after a quick read).

Comment: Seconded, looks good.